# Make a Program in Python that calculates the student's GPA?

Tags: python, function, return, average, gpa

I am in need of assistance on a coding question in Python.

I have to calculate a student’s GPA. The program must ask them how many classes they are taking, then ask them to enter the grades for each class and if it is weighted.

The program should then output the averaged GPA including the decimal place, and my main program must call the function.

The question gives a chart for the non-weighted and weighted number scores that correlates with the given letter grade: 
[gpa chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUPua.png)

Here's what I have so far:

```
def average (c): 
    div = c
    avg =(1.0*(sum(scores))/div)

#****************MAIN********************
c = input("How many classes are you taking?")
print ("You are taking " + str(c) + " classes.") 
x = input("Enter your letter grade.") 
w = int(input("Is it weighted? (1 = yes)")
    while (c <= 7): #Here it is saying that there is a syntax error because I input a while loop. I don't know why it is saying this. 
    if (x == A): 
        if (w == 1): 
            print ("Your GPA score is 5")
        else: 
            print ("Your GPA score is 4")
    elif (x == B): 
        if (w == 1): 
            print ("Your GPA score is 4")
        else: 
            print ("Your GPA score is 3") 

    elif (x == C): 
        if (w == 1): 
            print ("Your GPA score is 3")
        else: 
            print ("Your GPA score is 2") 

    elif (x == D): 
        if (w == 1): 
            print ("Your GPA score is 2") 
        else: 
            print ("Your GPA score is 1") 

    elif (x == F): 
        if ( w == 1): 
            print ("Your GPA score is 1")      
        else: 
            print ("Your GPA score is 0") 

    scores = []
    list.append(x)

    average(c)
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: What specifically are you asking for help with?

Comment: we don't have crystal balls here at SO. we need a bit more info on whats going on :(

Comment: I am asking if my code is viable or not. I am taking an Intro to Computer Science course through Edhesive and its code terminal keeps saying that there is "bad syntax" where the user is asked to input the value for c just after the main program starts. I am at a loss for what to do. Any help would be great!

Comment: That's not how you call functions in python. A `return` statement goes inside the function when it is defined, then later the function is called with `func()` or in your case, `classes(c)` or `gpacalc(x,w)` in your main block

Comment: Thank you very much @G.Anderson! That helps a lot.

Comment: Additionally, if you're asking about an error you're receiving, you should really include the error in your question, as that can help us guide you to the correct solution to a specific issue

Comment: Note also, that after you solve the above mentioned function call issues, you will continue wo see errors beacuse you never defien `w` to pass into the function, and you need to remember that, in python, `c` and `'c'` refer to different things, in this case a variable name vs a character. It may be worth taking a refresher course on some of these topics and trying to rewrite the whole code, IMO

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty evident that I'm a beginner...I just edited the post to show my current progress with the program. I also placed a hashtag where the code terminal says it identifies an error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you are asking for, but fixing just after the function definitions might be a good start

**Don't**

```py
def classes(c): 
print ("You are taking " + c  + " classes.")
```

**Do**

```py
def classes(c): 
    print ("You are taking " + c  + " classes.")
```

Comment: this, typographical error! python loves whitespace :D

Comment: Ok, that helps! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe? I didn't divide anything in classes but I want you to understand the logic:

```
number_class=None

while number_class==None:# I set-it up number_class=None so it will keep asking the number of classes until you introduce an integer value
    try:
        number_class=input("How many classes are you taking?")
    except:
        print "Error, the input should be a number!\n"

total_result=0#your score start from 0
i=0
while i<number_class:# i create a loop to insert the score for each class
    grade=raw_input("Enter your letter grade for the %s class." %(str(i+1)))

    grade=grade.upper()#convert the grate to upper so you are able to introduce a or A without make too many check
    if grade== 'A' or grade== 'B' or grade== 'C' or grade== 'D' or grade== 'F':#if you introduce a correct score we add it to the total sum and we go ahead with next class
        i+=1#next iteration
        if grade== 'A':
            total_result+=4
        elif grade== 'B':
            total_result+=3
        elif grade== 'C':
            total_result+=2
        elif grade== 'D':
            total_result+=1
        #elif: grade== 'F':#we can omitt F seeing that it's =0
        #    total_result+=0
        print total_result
    else:# if you introduce a wrong input for the grade we ask you again without pass to next iteration
        print "Error, the grade should be: A, B, C, D or F!\n"


average="%.2f" % (float(total_result)/float(number_class))#we divided the total score for the number of classes using float to get decimal and converting on 2 decimal places
print "Your GPA is: %s" %(str(average))
```

Example:

```
How many classes are you taking?5
Enter your letter grade for the 1 class.A
4
Enter your letter grade for the 2 class.B
7
Enter your letter grade for the 3 class.C
9
Enter your letter grade for the 4 class.A
13
Enter your letter grade for the 5 class.B
16
Your GPA is: 3.20
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a ton. However, when I tried running it on CodeSkulptor, the input where it asks for the letter grade of each class keeps repeating without stopping. Is there any trigger that will stop it?

Comment: It ask the grade for how many classes you choose, if you notice it saw as well 1 class, second class etc... I think is better you delete the sum of score of grade, I printed out just to check that it was correct