# Edhesive 7.5 code practice GPA average Python

Tags: python

Currently my code is:

```
def GPAcalc(grade, weighted):
   grade = grade.lower()
   dictionary = {"a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 2, "d": 1, "f": 0}
   if weighted == 1 and grade in dictionary:
       return "Your GPA score is: "+str(dictionary[grade] + 1)
     
   elif weighted == 0 and grade in dictionary:
       return "Your GPA score is: "+str(dictionary[grade])
   else:
       return "Invalid"

def GPAav():
    grade = GPAcalc()
    for i in range(0,cl):
        grad= GPAcalc(grade,dictionary)
        total = grade + total
        print(total/cl)
cl = int(input("How many Classes are you taking? "))
for i in range(0,cl):
    print(GPAcalc(input("Enter your letter Grade: "), int(input("Is it weighted?(1= yes, 0= no) "))))
GPAav()
```

I have to find the average GPA in decimal form from the rest of the code and output it. How would I go about getting the values from GPAcalc and using it in GPAav so i can average it out?

Comment: What is the difference between what you want and your current code?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54751618/4267439

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here. Store the grades in an list as they are entered or do the calculations on the fly. I chose the first option. This allows you to use the data later, if you want to add features the the app. You may also want to store the un-weighted grades in a list of tuples (`[('a',True),('b',False)...]`), but I just store the weighted grades.

Also, it is probably easier if you verify that the user is inputting the correct values as you read them. Have them keep re-trying until they get it right.

Your calculation functions should not print anything. They should just do the calculations they are required to do and return the result as a number.

```
grade_map = {"a": 4, "b": 3, "c": 2, "d": 1, "f": 0}

def GPAcalc(grade, weighted):
   # Data has already been sanitized, so no error checks needed
   return grade_map[grade] + weighted

def GPAav(grades):
    return sum(grades) / len(grades)

def input_grades():
    # TODO: Make sure user enters a number
    cl = int(input("How many classes are you taking? "))
    grades = []
    for _ in range(cl):
        # Loop until valid input
        while True:
            # Get input and convert to lower case
            grade = input("Enter your letter grade: ").lower()
            if grade in grade_map:
                # Ok data. Exit loop.
                break
            # This only prints on bad input
            print("Invalid input. Enter a,b,c,d or f. Try again...")
        # Loop until valid input
        while True:
            # Read the value as a string first to verify "0" or "1"
            weighted = input("Is it weighted?(1= yes, 0= no) ")
            if weighted in "01":
                # Verified. Now convert to int to avoid an exception
                weighted = int(weighted)
                break
            print("Invalid input. Enter 0 or 1. Try again...")
        # Store weighted numeric grade in list
        grades.append(GPAcalc(grade, weighted))
    return grades

grades = input_grades()
print(f"Your average GPA is {GPAav(grades)}.")
```

TODO: The repeated code in `input_grades()` is a red-flag that maybe that code can be moved into a re-usable function.

Comment: I took from this and mixed it with my own code but i keep getting this "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' on line 15" referring to the GPAav function

Comment: @ButterCCM I would have to see the code. The code in my answer does not give any errors: https://repl.it/@JohnnyMopp/CarpalWrithingSquare#main.py

Comment: huh, strange, must be the thing im using to compile for school